# Bitcoind configuration on Mac OS X?

Tags: bitcoind, php

I downloaded bitcoin-qt on my computer, and I'm trying to create a PHP web application with bitcoins and am following this guide: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/PHP_developer_intro

how do I change the configuration for bitcoind given that all I can download for a mac is bitcoin-qt? do I need to get a linux VM in order to have something setup? I was thinking of using XAMPP for my Apache MySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not mean to sound rude (and i am not trying so I apologize if i come off as such). But you need to read some more documentation and learn the basics of bitcoin.
This page is a really good place to get ideas https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin
Tt tells us that we CAN use the -qt version of bitcoin to allow json-rpc by adding a line to the bitcoin.conf file

the bitcoin.conf file is usualy located

/Users/username/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/bitcoin.conf

Add this line to the bitcoin.conf

server=1

Now the reason it is 1 versus 0 is because we want it on.

Also you need to add a username and password for your rpc connections

rpcuser=insertuserhere
rpcpassword=passwordgoeshere

Also did you take a look at the documentation for building headless bitcoin before starting? I do not know if there is a bitcoind binary build for macosx

The osx build instructions and notes readme available here runs you through the steps.
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md

Also, for development purposes xampp is fine but please do not use it on a production device, it is riddled with security flaws and holes. And if you do not decide to listen to my advice, let me tell you the story of how 150 btc were stolen by my lack of security. I used xampp and i used drupal. i used the security methods described for both. but there was a security flaw that was undiscovered at the time and poof it was gone.
if you MUST HAVE xampp then please for satoshi's sake harden the server as best you can
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15310/securing-firewalls-for-xampp-on-mac-os-x

Please let me know if i can help you more. I am more than glad to spend some time running through code. and helping some basic trouble shooting. but my warning: Be careful and do EXTENSIVE testing before you start using bitcoin out in the "Wild Wild West" aka the WorldWideWeb - Many people have such insecure set ups that it is a shock more funds are not stolen. Remember, bitcoins are money, every hacker will want money.

Thanks again for reading, good luck. Keep in touch

Comment: Hey Joe, thanks a lot for your help! I have another question that I asked because I'm running into errors with XAMPP talking to bitcoind would really appreciate if you could look at it (:

Comment: Here's teh link to it: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/13914/json-rpc-library-unable-to-connect-to-bitcoind

Comment: hi, sorry for the delay. I will reply shortly to the other post. and You are welcome!