# How to set up my Bitcoin RPC address once ive installed bitcoin core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, json-rpc, mac, bitcoin.conf

I have just set up bitcoin core on my macbook and im wondering how to get my http://login:password@ip:port address set up so i can interact with it. I am a complete noob to running a btc node so some help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

If Bitcoin Core on Mac is similar to Windows, you need only to find or create the configuration file and add the `rpcuser` and `rpcpassword` entries to specify values for your `login` and `password`. Then invoke `bitcoind` and test from another command/terminal window using something like `curl` on the same machine. Use `localhost` for `ip`, use `8332` for `port`. Progress from there *in small steps*. Don't try to run before you can crawl.

Relevant links

- [Bitcoind configuration on Mac OS X?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/13873/13866)
- [questions about rpcuser](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=rpcuser)
- [Troubleshooting RPC](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/118921/13866)